# 'Can't take screenshot due to security policy.'

Tags: chrome-for-android, browser

As you know that some sites/apps don't allow to take screenshots with a flashing message 'Can't take screenshot due to security policy.'

Is there anyway to get screenshot from these sites/apps ?